# DOMDocument->loadHTMLFile not fully working in loop

Tags: php, domdocument

I have an array of urls (pointing to an external website) and I want to get the images from these pages. I get a DOMDocument from each url in a loop and it works fine at first, but after ~20 links the function keeps returning false.

The more I refresh the page, the less links will be successfully processed. My only idea is that the website I am requesting is maybe not allowing so many requests at the time, but even if it was the case I don't know how to fix this. Here's the simple loop I use to get the DOMDocuments :

```php
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $docImg = new DOMDocument();
    $ok = $docImg->loadHTMLFile($link);
    if(!$ok) {
    echo $link;
}
```

Comment: Use [sleep()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) after each time you fetch a link

Comment: Do you have a list of links which can help reproduce this problem?

Comment: The website might have a rate limit that you're exceeding. @AlonEitan's suggestion will work around that.

Comment: @AlonEitan using sleep() works, thank you ! The answer was so simple I couldn't even see it. Could you answer so I can mark the problem as solved ?

Comment: well, how to prevent from request timeout error though ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use sleep() each time before fetching function